# How to change layer order during animation?

Tags: layers, adobe-after-effects

I'm producing an animation and I'd like one object to be in front of the other, and then to be behind. Then repeat the process. They would be alternating, sort of like the effect of two snakes intertwining.

[image]

**Other example:**

[image]

[image]

I would like to know how to do this, change layer order **during animation**.

I looked for several terms in my language, but I couldn't find them. I tried to look up these same terms in English, but without success.

**Animation Video (5 seconds):**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjQXPMIRrv0

**Images from video:**

[image]

[image]

Realize that I would like this alternation between blue and green rockets. In the animation only the green is in front, which doesn't give the "interlacing" effect.

I looked for the terms: interlacing, depth, inverting layers.

Comment: Video editing questions are [off-topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Sorry about that.  Try posting on Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: @BillyKerr I managed to solve my problem, would post an answer here. Rather, is it better to delete the question?

Comment: It's up to you. You can delete it if you want, or flag your question and ask the mods to migrate it to Video Production Stack Exchange if you are still looking for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To do this you will need to:**

- create a camera
- turn rocket layers into 3D

Once this is done, you will change the position of the rockets on the Z axis.

**Note that you only need to move one of the rockets in layer Z (back and forth):**

[image]